# Expire and Update records with Merge on condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

So the high level logic would be to expire records that match certain conditions and insert a new record.
Due to complexity of source and various Update/Insert requirement My INSERT, UPDATE query is taking very long. And I thought it is a good sign to use MERGE, but got stuck already at the start of implementation.

I assume that I could've done some error in logic otherwise I don't understand why there is no option to MERGE INSERT on MATCH.

Here is a general overview of tables involved, for simplicity I won't show the whole structure of source. I will show tables playing main role.

Let's say the target table is **B**
The source table is  **A**

First **A** can contain invalid records that we won't pass to target. So when we do JOIN condition on **B**  We will make sure that **A** has valid records  present in **B**.
If they are not we delete them and send to error table.
If they are we expire **B** record and insert new **A** valid record.

Here is a general overview of query.

```
select distinct
NewTerritoryId ,
customerid,
NewProductid,
Start_Date,
End_Date,
into #WIPtable
from **B** tm
JOIN (select  Start_Date, End_Date, productid, NewTerritory, OldTerritory, 

from **A**) S
ON S.OldTerritory = tm.Territory AND S.OldProduct = tm.Product AND S.customer = tm.customer

-- we insert it into temp table since we still need original **B** records  to expire them





UPDATE tm
SET
tm.EndDate  =GETDATE()

from **B**  tm
JOIN (select  Start_Date, End_Date, productid, NewTerritory, OldTerritory, 

from **A**) S
ON S.OldTerritory = tm.Territory AND S.OldProduct = tm.Product AND S.customer = tm.customer

-- we now expire current **B** records without affecting new  records


INSERT INTO **B**(Territoryid, customerid, ProductId, StartDate, EndDate)
SELECT
NewTerritoryId ,
customerid,
NewProductid,
Start_Date,
End_Date,
from #WIPtable
```

In fact it is more more complex with other conditions and has bunch of other scripts running in the middle. But this is the main part I expected to work with Merge.

As you could find, I insert record only when source table MATCHES records in target table, what is not allowed in MERGE. Why is that ?

Am I missing something important here ?

- Sample Data of B (target)

| customer | product | territory | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 991AOE211 | A | US | 01/01/2021 | 31/12/2021 |
| 991AOE211 | A | Germany | 01/01/2021 | 31/12/2021 |
| 991AOE211 | B | France | 01/01/2021 | 31/12/2021 |
| 881COE211 | B | Germany | 01/01/2021 | 31/12/2021 |
| 881COE211 | B | US | 01/01/2021 | 31/12/2021 |

Sample Data of A (source)

| customer | oldproduct | newproduct | oldterritory | newterritory | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 991AOE211 | A | B | US | US | 11/09/2021 | 31/12/2021 |
| 991AOE211 | B | A | Italy | Canada | 12/09/2021 | 31/12/2021 |
| 991AOE211 | B | B | France | Canada | 12/09/2021 | 31/12/2021 |

Expected result of table B after desired MERGE (or provided script)

| customer | product | territory | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 991AOE211 | A | US | 01/01/2021 | 11/09/2021 |
| 991AOE211 | B | US | 11/09/2021 | 31/12/2021 |
| 991AOE211 | A | Germany | 01/01/2021 | 31/12/2021 |
| 991AOE211 | B | France | 01/01/2021 | 11/09/2021 |
| 991AOE211 | B | Canada | 12/01/2021 | 11/09/2021 |
| 881COE211 | B | Germany | 01/01/2021 | 31/12/2021 |
| 881COE211 | B | US | 01/01/2021 | 31/12/2021 |

From the result you might notice that 2nd row of A table didn't pass to table B since it doesn't contain such record in tale B
Other records expired (closed EndDate to today) current records that match on customer, product, territory and added a new record that is up to date

Comment: Completely confused about which table you are trying to modify and under what conditions. Can you make it clearer? And there are some syntax errors in your script, please fix. Sample data and expected results would help immensely

Comment: I am modifying table B  under customerid, productid, territoryid conditions. First step is to expire these records that match these conditions based on A source table. Then insert new A records that match these conditions. The key field is customerid it never changes, but territory and product do change, but in order to track these changes we need to first match them  on  old product, territory to expire old record and add proper new. I will add  some data